# Sailsjs - Auto route for models in folder

Tags: model, sails.js

I generate API by sails generate API admin/user and get this

```
controllers

---admin

------user.js

models

---Admin

------user.js
```

I could call this API from route `http://localhost:1337/user/create`

But I want to call it from `http://localhost:1337/admin/user/create`

Could anyone tell a way to automatically generate API with folder name? I don't want to define route manually.

Answer (score 0):

According to sails.js official document

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/command-line-interface/sails-generate

there is no command that generate API route automatically. You need to create route manually.

Because Sails.js don't know that you are creating API for performing which CRUD operation. So how Sails.js define route method (i.e GET or POST or PUT).

For best practice API end-point is always design by developer.

Comment: Sails provide automatically route following model like create, update, destroy. In my example I could add record with this url http://localhost:1337/user/create. My question is about model in folder. Tks for your answer but it doesnot relates to my question